# How do I get the wireless working on an HP Pavilion dv6?

Tags: wireless, 13.04, broadcom

I got a HP Pavilion dv6 which has a broadcom wifi module which worked fine the day before I upgraded to 13.04 (Kubuntu). The driver is still installed and it tries to establish a connection (all wifi networks around are correctly detected). However, I cannot further than "setting up network address".

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Can you add your hardware information to the question even though you have an answer? It will help people looking for that specific wireless card in search engines, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?62541-Wifi-no-longer-working-after-update-to-13-04 this solved my problem (disable 3rd party drivers):

> Check your additional drivers, if the proprietary driver is active try deactivating it and reboot.
>
> This fixed my wifi problem.

Comment: this worked but the wifi speed is really slow without using the proprietary driver.